# Is there a way to inherit a PyTypeObject from a Python library into a custom type in CPython?

Tags: python, c, inheritance, cpython

I'm trying to create a custom type in CPython that inherits from an already defined type object in Python. My approach thus far is to use `PyImport_ImportModule`, then access the `PyTypeObject` and set it to the `tp_base` attribute in my `PyTypeObject`.

Importing:

```
PyTypeObject typeObj = {...} // Previously defined PyTypeObject for a fallback

int init() {
    PyObject* obj = PyImport_ImportModule("<absolute_path_to_python_module>");
    if (obj && PyObject_HasString(obj, "<python_type_object>")) {
        PyTypeObject* type_ptr = (PyTypeObject*) PyObject_GetAttrString(obj, "<python_type_object>");
        typeObj = *type_ptr;
    }
    if (PyType_Ready(&typeObj) < 0) return -1;
    ... // Other initialization stuff
}
```

Inheriting:

```
PyTypeObject CustomType = {
    ... // Initialization stuff
    .tp_base = &typeObj;
};
```

The custom type is able to inherit the functions, but fails on `isInstance(CustomType(), TypeObj)`. When I try to access the `__bases__` attribute of the custom type, it raises a segmentation fault.

Comment: Non-heap-types (most C classes) aren't designed to inherit from heap types (types written in Python, plus a few weird C classes).

Comment: Also `typeObj = *type_ptr;` is doing something completely unsafe and unsupported - you can't copy *any* Python object like that.

Comment: So am I suppose to allocate memory on the heap, i.e. use ```malloc```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Types are identified by identity, not value. When you try to do `typeObj = *type_ptr;`, even if it "works", `typeObj` has a different memory address than `*type_ptr`, and will never be considered the same type. You need to preserve the identity.

Change your code to something like:

```
PyTypeObject fallback_type_obj = {...} // Previously defined PyTypeObject for a fallback
PyTypeObject *type_ptr = NULL;

int init() {
    PyObject* obj = PyImport_ImportModule("<absolute_path_to_python_module>");
    if (obj && PyObject_HasString(obj, "<python_type_object>")) {
        type_ptr = (PyTypeObject*) PyObject_GetAttrString(obj, "<python_type_object>");
    }
    if (type_ptr == NULL) {
        if (PyType_Ready(&fallback_type_obj) < 0) return -1;
        type_ptr = &fallback_type_obj;
    }
    ... // Other initialization stuff
}
```

You then make a heap type that uses `type_ptr` as the base (a static/global type won't work, since `type_ptr` isn't initialized to anything useful statically).